# Threading a function that relies on another class in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, game-engine, procedural-generation

I am trying to build an endless terrain generator (followed this tutorial by Sebastian Lague: [Tutorial Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0m73RsBik4&t=307s)) where he implements threading for the generation of the terrain and mesh. I went a step further and created a tool to place Gameobjects on the terrain (trees, rocks, etc.) now I cannot figure out how I would use threading there... I am trying things out since days, but reached a point where I'd like to ask for help. Hope some sort of Pro can help me out on this.

Here's the commented code and a attempt of mine to solve my problem:

```
public GameObject grasGeneratorPrefab;
public GameObject physicsSimulatorPrefab;
public bool updateGras = false;
private bool allowGrasUpdate = false;

// Check if instance at this point already exists --> if YES, don't instantiate another.
HashSet<Transform> alreadyGeneratedObjectAtThisChunkTransform = new HashSet<Transform>();

Queue<AssetDataInfoThread<AssetData>> assetDataInfoQueue = new Queue<AssetDataInfoThread<AssetData>>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    allowGrasUpdate = false;
    StartCoroutine (WaitForFirstObjectPlacement ());
}

// First time instantiating Gameobjects on terrain
IEnumerator WaitForFirstObjectPlacement()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
    foreach (Transform t in this.transform) 
    {
        PlaceObjectsOnChunks ();
    }
    allowGrasUpdate = true;

}

// I WANT THIS FUNCTION TO BE THREADED --> To prevent freezes during execution
public void PlaceObjectsOnChunks()
{
    foreach (Transform t in this.transform) 
    {
        // If the Transform-object has a collider and the TRansform is yet not in the List...
        if (t.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().sharedMesh != null && !alreadyGeneratedObjectAtThisChunkTransform.Contains(t)) 
        {
            // ...execute this function
            AssetPlacement.SpawnGrassGeneratorAtChunkPosition (t.transform.position, grasGeneratorPrefab);

            // THE FUNCTION THAT IS PICKED FROM AssetPlacement class is:

  //                public static void SpawnGrassGeneratorAtChunkPosition(Vector3 centre, GameObject grasGeneratorPrefab)
  //                {
  //                    GameObject grasG = Object.Instantiate (grasGeneratorPrefab, new Vector3 (centre.x, 0, centre.z), Quaternion.identity);
  //                }

            AssetPlacement.SpawnPhysicsSimulatorsAtChunkPosition (t.transform.position, physicsSimulatorPrefab);

            // same function as SpawnGrassGeneratorAtChunkPosition with other prefab

            alreadyGeneratedObjectAtThisChunkTransform.Add (t); // Add Transform to the List (to be checked in next iteration)
        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (allowGrasUpdate && AssetPlacement.updateGras)
    {

        PlaceObjectsOnChunks();

        // Triggers the Stop for the Function
        AssetPlacement.StopGrasUpdate ();
    }

    // /// // // // // // // //  // // // 
    //  // TRYING OUT WITH THREADING // //  __> Need help here
    // /// // // // // // // //  // // //


    if(assetDataInfoQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < assetDataInfoQueue.Count; i++) 
        {
            AssetDataInfoThread<AssetData> threadInfo = assetDataInfoQueue.Dequeue();
            threadInfo.callback (threadInfo.parameter);
            Debug.Log ("Reached crucial threading point");
        }
    }
}



public void RequestAssetToPlaceData(Action<AssetData> callback)
{
    ThreadStart threadStart = delegate {

        AssetDataThread(callback);
    };

    new Thread (threadStart).Start ();
}

void AssetDataThread(Action<AssetData> callback)
{
    AssetData assetData = PlaceObjectsOnChunks();
    lock (assetDataInfoQueue) {
        assetDataInfoQueue.Enqueue (new AssetDataInfoThread<AssetData> (callback, assetData));
    }
}

// DO I NEED THIS STRUCT (?)
public struct AssetData
{
    public  Vector3 centre; // These values are used in AssetPlacement-Script
    public readonly GameObject prefab; // These values are used in AssetPlacement-Script

    public AssetData (Vector3 centre, GameObject prefab)
    {
        this.centre = centre;
        this.prefab = prefab;
    }

}

struct AssetDataInfoThread<T>
{
    public readonly Action<T> callback;
    public readonly T parameter;
    public AssetDataInfoThread (Action<T> callback, T parameter)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please refer [ask] for some guidane on how to ask.

Comment: @TobiasTheel My question is: How can I call PlaceObjectsOnChunks() in a separate thread?

Comment: FYI: Corourtines are not threads. Coroutines are a synchronous task scheduling system and all coroutine code runs on the main thread.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I know that. That Coroutine in my code is just for 1 initial set up (in fact you can ignore it). I just wanted to know if it is possible to run _PLaceObjectOnChunks_ in a separate thread. When I do so, I get the error that I cannot call get_transfrom outside of the main threat. This is logical. So i need to find a way to work around that. I found a pretty nice help at [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-threading-helper.90128/) I will try this out. By the way thx for editing my errors in my other question.

Comment: I don't think you can instantiate from a child thread. A lot of Unity core methods require being run from the main thread, I think `Instantiate` is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

When I followed Sebastian Lague's tutorial I found it was really great to start of on landmass generation but I found that it was limited when getting to expand it's functionality. Here's my experience with what you are trying to do. I hope maybe it gives some insight, help, ideas or avoids for your project.

### My Solution

I found that the only way I could add a new `generation layer` on top of the main mesh generation was when I had generated the terrain for the next chunk. Then i'd fire a new thread and get a `list` of `suitable locations` for objects based on the `height` and `angle` of the terrain.

Once I had suitable locations in a list I had a function that would randomly assign object to position these objects would be something like:

- Trees
- Rocks
- Chests
- Roots

Once the thread has finished I'd place the objects as the players `view distance` was about to be in `LOS` of the object.

[Video of the suitable locations script in chunk](https://i.gyazo.com/a909cf6f5ea9a5e4625044a76439a724.mp4)

This clip reinforces what I've talked about. Unfortunately I don't have the code anymore.

Here's example of the menu when generating the chunk of the map the camera was in.

[image: Example of generation]

[image: Terrain Object Generation]

Negatives:

- Lack of perfect placement of objects
- Scalability may be issue when spawning large amounts of objects
- Lack of consistency of object placement

Improvements I was going to make:

- Multi thread each object layer
- Implement `suitable locations` when Chunks were generated at a one time generation perfomance cost
- Implement `Object Layers` at chunk level so it keeps each chunk looking the same every time it's loaded

Comment: Great reply! Thx a lot for it so far. I cannot check it right now, but as soon as I am I will come back at you :)

Comment: @M_NEN No worries. I think you'll mostly extract some value from it. But like most of the time in Game development you just go with what works and there's no one way of doing it!

Comment: Here I am again. Thx once more for sharing your solution. I see the point and I think it makes totally sense in your project. The thing with mine is that I use the function I want to put in a separate thread also for placing a point cloud generator that populates gras later on. So I really need to find a way to place  _PlaceObjectsOnChunks()_ in a separate thread, otherwise it is not accurate enough... maybe you know how I'd do that(Execute _PlaceObjectsOnChunks()_ in a separate thread)? Have a great eve man

Comment: @M_NEN There's some good discussions and pages about community doing threading as the Unity Docs of not the best. take a look at these http://blog.universityofgames.net/using-threads-with-unity or this https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-no-multithreading-with-unity-objects.194724/ Unfortunetly I no longer develop in unity so my knowledge is limited as of PointCloud Generation